# Separating string to multiple integers

Tags: c

please, how I can convert this:

```
char infix[] = "123+354*87/156=" (can be variable)
```

How to separate number's from this string (to integers, like 123 354 87 156, no to 1 2 3 3 5 4...) and char (chars + * / ).

Comment: This is called "lexing" or "tokenizing" and is a well-studied problem in computer science. How do you want the data to be formatted? What have you tried?

Comment: Take a look at strtok: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html

Comment: i saving it to tokens (struct - int and char), but still had problem with converting int (strtol) and then getting char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need to build a simple calculator... If you're planning to do this from scratch, you gonna need some background from [Compiling Theory](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/farrell/compmain.html), and use concepts like Finite State Machine, Parsing, etc.

But there are a lot of tools that can make this task easier: lex/yacc (C), flex/bison (C++) or COCO/R (many languages).

This is a SIMPLE example in C that splits the string in numbers (state=NUM) and symbols (state=SYM):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NONE    0
#define NUM 1
#define SYM 2

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char infix[] = "123+354*87/156=";
    char buffer[10];
    int i, j;
    int state = NONE;
    char c;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while(i < strlen(infix)) {
        c = infix[i];
        switch(state) {
            case NUM:
                if ( isdigit(c) ) {
                    buffer[j++] = c;
                    buffer[j] = 0;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    printf("%s\n", buffer);
                    j = 0;
                    state = NONE;
                }
                break;
            case SYM:
                i++;
                printf("%c\n", c);
                state = NONE;
                break;
            case NONE:
                if ( isdigit(c) ) state = NUM;
                else state = SYM;
                break;
        }
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, yea, I was searching for this... I finally used my code similar this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char infix[] = "123+354*87/156=";
    char *p = infix;
    while(1)
    {
        if(*p == '\0')
            break;
        if(*p == '+' || *p == '*' ||*p == '/' ||*p == '=' || *p == '-')
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        else
            printf("%c", *p);
        p++;

    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123 354 87 156
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use C++ and each operator has a length of one char, and string has the form "number operator number operator ... number operator" (that means begins with number, ends with operator and switches always between both) then use istringstream:

```
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char infix[] = "123+345*87/156=";
    istringstream is(infix);

    double nums[999]; // maybe you need more than 999
    char chars[999];
    int nums_pos = 0;
    int chars_pos = 0;
    bool number = true; // begin with number

    while (!is.eof())
    {
        if (number)
        {
            is >> nums[nums_pos];
            nums_pos++;
            number = false;
        }
        else
        {
            is >> chars[chars_pos];
            chars_pos++;
            number = true;
        }
    }

    // you got nums_pos-1 numbers and chars_pos chars
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another possible way but in C as you asked...

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char infix[] = "123+354*87/156=";
    int curVal = 0;

    // For each character in infix
    for(char *p = infix; *p != '\0'; ++p)
    {
        // If it is not a ascii numeral
        if(*p > '9' || *p < '0')
        {
            // Output value
            printf("%d\n", curVal/10);

            // Output char
            printf("%c\n", *p);

            curVal = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Accumulate the individual digits 
            curVal += (*p) - '0';
            curVal *= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

It will output:

```
123
+
354
*
87
/
156
=
```